# Bash script with expect

Tags: bash, expect

I have the simplest script ever:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
expect "hello"
send -- "ll \r"
```

When I run it, I manually type "hello" word and that ll command never runs ...

Afterwards I put `exp_internal 1` and then this comes up

```
[root@localhost tmp]# ./file1.exp

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "hello"? no
hello

expect: does "hello\n" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "hello"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "hello"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp0"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "hello"
}end: sending "ll \r" to { exp0 ll
[root@localhost tmp]#
```

Can anyone explains me why the command is not being ran as command ?

Comment: Why *would* it be run as a command? You're not telling Expect to spawn a shell, so you're certainly not telling it to send `ll` *to* a shell. (Which is just as well, because your `expect "hello"` would never work if Expect thought that the `hello` was supposed to come from the shell it had spawned.) You should just Google for an Expect tutorial, or even just look at the examples at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect